# I am unable to post comments to questions or answers

Tags: support, comments

In the last hour or so I have attempted to add comments to questions or answers in ELU and when I've clicked Post the comment just went into the bitbucket.  Is anyone else getting this?  Also, the usual text below the comment entry box is not showing the usual "X characters left".

I've tried entering comments in this same account in SO, and it is working normally there.

CORRECTED.  It is ELU, not ELL.  I am also unable to post comments here in Meta.

Edited to add: I tried restarting browser but nothing changes.  Can post comment to SO, but not ELU/incl.Meta.  FWIW I am using IE10.

Comment: the op has a user on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/users/20156/cyberherbalist
I couldn't reproduce the issue though...

Comment: OK, figured it out.  See my answer below.

Comment: @m0sa, can you reproduce the behavior with Compatibility ON?

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason,  the browser tab I was accessing ELU with was set with Compatibility ON.  When I turned it OFF, the issue went away.

I don't know why this is!

Might this still be a bug?

Comment: It's more likely to be a bug in IE10 and its implementation of "Compatibility" mode, whatever that is supposed to do.

Comment: "Compatibility" with what exactly, I wonder...?

Comment: If this is not a rhetorical question, "compatibility" in this case means for the more advanced browser to be set to more closely mimic the rendering of the less advanced one for a given page or site which may not have all the features.  See http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1196-internet-explorer-compatibility-view-turn-off.html